# Get the value from unmanaged code to managed code

Tags: c#, unmanaged

I need to get the value from `C` unmanaged code. Actually I called the function from unmanaged, the function's return type is point where point is a structure.

*The structure mentioned following manner*

```
typedef struct point
{
    Poly* pol;
    NL_DEGREE p;
    VECTOR* vec;
} Point;
```

Where `Poly` and `VECTOR`  are structure.

Actually I got the return value point as `IntPtr` in `C#`.After getting the value of `IntPtr`, I tried to convert this `Intptr` to an `Array`. Converting the `Array` in this below manner.

```
point[] Q = new point[2];
int size= Marshal.SizeOf(new point());
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Q[i] = (point)Marshal.PtrToStructure(new IntPtr(Qptr.ToInt32() + (i * size)), typeof(point));
}
```

But after getting the array the value of each structure element became null.What I made wrong on this, Please anyone suggest me......

I mentioned the structure created in c# detaily below.

```
public unsafe struct point
        {
            public Poly* pol;
            public NL_DEGREE p;
            public vECTOR* knt;
        }
```

where poly

```
public unsafe struct Poly
        { 
            public Int32 n;
            public cpoint* Pw;
        }
```

coint is also a structure

```
public struct cpoint
        {
            public double x;
            public double y;
            public double z;
            public double w;
        }
```

where VECTOR

```
 public unsafe struct VECTOR
        {            
            public Int32 m;
            public double *U;          

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

from you code snippet it's unclear how exactly struct is defined in C. Assuming some default alignment your C# definition should look like:

```
public class Point
{
  IntPtr pol;
  NL_DEGREE       p;
  IntPtr vec;
}
```

you would still have to consider exact struct layout with appropriate Pack size (see [1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack(v=vs.110).aspx) for details)

so in your code you would have to do the following:

```
var point = (Point)Marshal.PtrToStructure(ptr, typeof(Point));
var poly = (Poly)Marshal.PtrToStructure(point.pol, typeof(Poly));
var vector = (Vector)Marshal.PtrToStructure(point.vec, typeof(Vector));
```

since both Poly and Vector may be arrays you may want to use IntPtr.Add() [2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.add(v=vs.110).aspx) method to iterate over these arrays.

[StructLayoutAttribute.Pack Field](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.pack(v=vs.110).aspx)

[IntPtr.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.add(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank for answering, I have put the detail of structure which created in c# edited in same post